# How to change the Cursor size?

Tags: java, cursor, awt

I want to change the size of Cursor in java. So please can somebody tell me how can i do this. i have searched on google but i did not find any solution. Below is my code from which i am trying to change the size of cursor.

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
InputStream imgStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/move_cursor.gif");

BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(10,10, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
try {
    bi = ImageIO.read(imgStream);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
}
Point hotspot = new Point(0,0);
ImageIcon myImg = new ImageIcon(bi);

Image image = myImg.getImage();

toolkit.getBestCursorSize(10, 10);
Cursor cursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(image,hotspot ,"Custom Cursor");
setCursor(cursor);
```

This code has changed the cursor(which is a image) but did not changed the size of cursor.
Please give me the solution for that.

thanks

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The size of the cursor is platform dependent. For example, it can't be changed and I think it's limited to 32x32

Comment: The size may be 32x32, but you can make yourself a smaller one, with transparent background 32x32. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620188/how-to-set-custom-size-for-cursor-in-swing